# Визуальный редактор для EF 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

В проекте использую `Ef 7`, однако все время приходится ручками писать связи и прочее, что не совсем есть хорошо. Раньше можно было через диаграмму все делать `(Model first)`, но почему то до сих пор нет такой возможность в `VS2015`. Проект `asp.net core`

Посоветуйте визуальный редактор который упростит работу по проектированию классов базы данных для `Entity Framework 7`

Comment: [таких нет, судя по всему](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx)

Comment: ну елы палы) как так

Comment: Ручками всё, ручками. Визуальные редакторы это для детей.

Comment: Если судить вашей логике тогда и кодить надо в блокноте нежели в ide

Comment: если вы хотите рисовать бд  в визуальном редакторе то Вам может подойти подход `Database First`(вроде бы данный подход остается)